# angular pwa not working offline while service workers are loadded in online mode

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

the service workers are loaded as you can see when its online mode
[image]

but when its offline mode the service worker doesn't load.
[image]

the link to the code is on https://github.com/abrshdir/test
**and** the link where i uploaded the generated build is on https://abrshdir.github.io/production

i have gone across all the questions regarding this issue but not any one of them can work. What am i missing here?

Comment: I don't know why some people make it discouraging to ask question in here? You know it takes time to upload in here and wait for answers!

Comment: For future reference: It seems like the problem was github pages afterall because the same production build worked on firebase without any flows. But if anybody made it to work on github please put a link and how it was able to work.

Comment: I have similar but slightly different problem can you please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63182577/11826523